# Create an array of Raspberry Pi Computer modules

Tags: pi-3

Has anyone looked into or know of the possibility of creating an array of Raspberry PI computer 3 modules?  I would like something like a carrier board capable of holding 4 to 16 of the modules with, maybe, an ethernet interface.   In that manner, multiple carrier boards could work together to become what might be called a small super-computer.  I am a software engineer, not hardware.  I have never programmed multiple processors but do have some projects I would like to start.

Comment: have you done any research? ... there are some projects like that on the web

Comment: please ask a question about the Raspberry Pi, not about the existence of a person posessing specific knowledge

Comment: The goal is to use Raspberry PI compute 3 boards to build a multiprocessor computer.  Those boards will provide the greatest bang for the buck.

And yes, I have been googling but my search terms are, quite apparently, insufficient.  Any clues of where to look will be appreciated.  If not, I will stop cluttering this board with this concept.

Comment: search term is `raspberry pi cluster`